# Python - Query on Text Mining & Indexing

Tags: python, text-mining

New to python and request someone to share a code snippet -

I have a table that contains 2 variables - Accident, Text description

I want to create a function (or combination of functions) in python to - create 2 indicators -

1. The indicator takes a value =1 if at least one of the following words (Type 1 words) - ('The', 'Metabolism', 'Rate of', 'The Man bought') are present in the description (free flow text), e.g., 'It was being thought that the metabolism rate of birds are higher than of animals. However, that is not true.'
2. The second indicator will take a value 1 if the criteria mentioned in condition 1. above is true ***AND if none of the words*** from the following (Negation words) - ('No', 'Not at all', 'Not 1', 'Nevertheless') is present in the same description at a given distance +x or -x from the Type 1 words mentioned in point 1 above.

The words and sentence given above are just for understanding. In essence, there will be these information pieces present -

1. A table containing text desciption (free flow text) and Name (ID)
2. A list of Type 1 words
3. A list of Negation words
4. A given distance (+x /-x) within which the negation words in point 3 above shouldn't be present

I'm using Python version 2.7. Would be helpful if someone can post a Python code for the same.

Xiaowei Zhu

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please show us what you have done so far? It'll help narrowing down your issue. Good luck!

Comment: I haven't really done anything so far. I want a complete code actually.

Comment: Please show us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are facing. If you cannot, you may need to consider hiring someone to do the job for you.